# Hyper-V on Windows 10: Clone guest?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, clone

This is about Hyper-V on Windows 10 Pro (the consumer / desktop flavor -- no "server" OS).

I am trying to clone a (linux) guest by exporting / importing it. Exporting succeeds, but importing gives an error message like the virtual hard disk I want to import already exists. Which is not exactly surprising, as I want to import the "clone" in parallel to the existing original machine.

It looks like I'd need to rename the machine while exported, but there seems no tooling for it and the exported files look kind of strange and I'd rather not try to do anything with them.

I must be missing something -- cloning is such an essential feature -- but it seems only possible here if for each "cloned" (imported) machine a different directory for location of the files is chosen, which is extremly cumbersome.

This question is not about anything "what to do with the guest after clone" (searching gives some hits about sysprep etc which is completely out of scope here since I have linux guests.)

Comment: Can you show us the exact error? A Snapshot for example.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot: http://imgur.com/M77fSTT (sorry, german)

Comment: Is there any option in Hyper V to modify the installation id?